# Storing MultipartFormDataInput files in a database, How can I later make it multipart again and forward the files?

Tags: java, postgresql, quarkus

Hi all I have a Quarkus REST client that recieves MultipartFormDataInput from a server. The data consists of files. I want to forward those files at a later stage. But can I store them in a database when MultipartFormDataInput is not serlizeable?

I've tried to store them as byte[]

```java
    public byte[] getByteArray(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("files");
        InputPart parts = inputParts.get(0);
        
        try {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(parts.getBody(InputStream.class, null));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }
```

This works for storage but when I later want to send this file it just sends

```bash
--2a783bc5-17ae-4e8a-8c44-83dd3be2b724
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1684ad73]
--2a783bc5-17ae-4e8a-8c44-83dd3be2b724--%
```

The method for sending is

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public MyFiles sendStoredFiles() throws IOException {
        MyFiles myFiles = new MyFiles();
        myFiles.add(getByteArrayFromDataSource());
        return myFiles;
    }
```

Update with suggestion from christoper

```java
@MultipartForm
public class MyFiles {
    @FormParam("files")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public List<byte []> files; // problem seems to be here that it is a list. but how can i send several files?

    public MyFiles(List<byte []> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public MyFiles() {
        files = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

This does still just give me

```java
--c9eeb97c-e5d2-442b-ad17-ebaef7581dd3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[[B@dbe8688]
--c9eeb97c-e5d2-442b-ad17-ebaef7581dd3--
```

as response

Comment: You're not storing bytes, but an `InputStream`. This could wouldn't compile. An `InputStream` needs to be read.

Comment: Update myfiles to byte[] in post. still does not give the correct output

Comment: Ok it works if it s just one file with byte[] but how do i send several files? I assume I can't append them to the byte array